# ImportError: No module named 'profiles'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Taking an online course. Cannot get a response from the Instructor.

I am using GIT BASH and I get an error on the runserver command.

Not sure if it matters, but have installed:

- GIT (2.21.0)
- Virtual Box (6.0.4)
- Vagrant (2.2.4)
- Atom Editor

I have installed django 1.11 with the command:

```
pip install django==1.11
```

I installed the restframework 3.6.2

```
pip install djangorestframework==3.6.2
```

I get to the point where I type:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

and I get the error:

## **No module named 'profiles'**

Here is the full error:

```
(profiles_api) vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant/src/profiles_project$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f51b1795378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 120, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'profiles'
```

If it helps: here are the **INSTALLED_APPS** on my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'profiles.api',
]
```

Hope I am asking it correctly. Any thoughts? Please let me know if I need to add anything else to make it clearer.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's `profiles.api` with a dot, and not `profiles_api`? Can you give what is inside `profiles.api` directory or the `apps.py` file?

Comment: Amazing. Something as simple as that. Thank you - really appreciate it. I changed it to profiles_api and works like a champ.